# Stopping call to getView of a list view

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a list view and each row consists of images that are placed according to the specific conditions. I have written all the validations in getView method of listView.

But the problem is when i scroll the list view up and down few times, the images are getting placed in random cells. Can I stop calls to the getView method when the activity is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The great thing with ListView is that you write adapter that constructs list items (`getView`)  and ListView takes care of the rest--tracks which items are visible, calls `getView` for any items that are about to become visible etc.

Your options are:

- fix your `getView()` so that it follows its contract correctly
- if you want to create your views just once, and there are not too many of them, maybe you don't need ListView at all, and can get by with e.g. ScrollView?